# External Content Types WCF Service SharePoint Designer connection error

Tags: office-365, rest, office-integration, soap

I am doing integration.And the product web service available online.I trying to to use service but it is showing an error.

follow these steps by selecting Add connection = wcf
[image: Service][image: WCF[![][2]]][3]